# Returning values using a query that have been awarded a bonus

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to `transactionId` that were randomly chosen to be awarded a bonus which is essentially just having their rewardValue be double.

Following is my schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE rewards (  
        rewardId    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        rewardType    VARCHAR(20), 
        rewardValue    NUMERIC(6,2)
    );

    CREATE TABLE deposit (   
        depositId    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        depositDate    DATE, 
        customerId    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Customers
    );

    CREATE TABLE transactions (   
        transactionId    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        depositId    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES Orders,
        transactionAmount   NUMERIC(18,2)
    );
```

Here's my query:

```
    select distinct t.transactionId 
    from transactions t join deposit d on t.depositId = d.depositId join 
         rewards r on 2 * r.rewardValue <= t.transactionAmount;
```

I get some output which is just a few values repeating over and over. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: provide your sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: You seem to be missing a join condition in your query.  Please tell us how all three tables are related to each other.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the post with join, it still repeats the same values, just in a different order

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the post again. is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 0):

before answer your question, seems like your join have a issue.
if you want to find transactions eligible for rewards 
try this ->

```
select distinct transactionId from
(select t.transactionId,r.rewardValue,t.transactionAmount
from transactions t join deposit d on t.depositId = d.depositId,rewards r ) tbl where  2*rewardValue <= transactionAmount
```